# Multiple Dispatch With Two Parameters?

Tags: java, oop, generics, polymorphism, dispatch

Here is the use case I am trying to support:

An **IDataStore** is an interface that specifies how to put data in the data store. It has two child interfaces, **IDataStoreA** and **IDataStoreB** which specify different ways to get data out of the data store.

An **ICalculator** specifies a way to perform calculations on the data.

I want to make an **ICalculationPerformer** class. This will take a specific implementation of IDataStore and ICalculator and specify the logic for how to get data out of the data store and pass it to the calculator.

```
public interface ICalculationPerformer<D extends IDataStore, C extends ICalculator>{
```

void performCalculation(D dataStore_, C calculator_);
}

An implementation might look like this:

```
public class ConcreteCalculationPerformer extends ICalculationPerformer<DataStoreA, CalculatorA>{
  void performCalculation(DataStoreA dataStore_, CalculatorA calculator_);
}
```

My main class has an ICalculationPerformer but doesn't know at compile time what its generics are; I get a raw type warning. Suppose it gets the ICalculationPerformer from a factory

```
class driver{
  IDataStore dataStore; //constructor injected via spring
  ICalculator calculator; //constructor injected via spring

public static void main(){
//raw type warning!
  ICalculationPerformer p = 
calculationPerformerFactory.getCalculationPerformer(dataStore,Calculator);

}
}
```

Is there any way to get around the raw type warning?

Comment: Your declaration of `ICalculatorPerformer` is using a raw type. Why can't you define the appropriate generic type `ICalculatorPerformer<IDataStore, ICalculator>`?

Comment: Because driver doesn't know which implementation of dataStore and calculator it is using. All we know if that we have an IDataStore and ICalculator, but maybe we want to have an ICalculationPerformer<DataStoreA, CalculatorB>

Comment: Then you are expecting something that `ICalculatorPerformer<? extends IDataStore, ? extends ICalculator>`? Isn't so?

Comment: Correct, I'll try that and see if it fixes the raw type warning

Comment: That causes an error: when I invoke p.performCalculation<datastore, calculator>, it prompts tells me that the method is not applicable for the arguments (ICalcKeyToTermMap, IFormulaCalc)